# mysql perform union with more join tables

Tags: mysql, join, union

As shown in below image I need to filter all the customers with and without loans .

[image]

**Here is my mysql query :**

```
SELECT
    cum.id,
    lhh.mst_customer_id,
    cum.first_name,
    cum.middle_name,
    cum.last_name,
    cum.name_ins,
    lhh.loan_amount,
    lhh.date_granted,
    lhh.loan_duration,
    lhh.status
FROM
    loan_management_app.trans_cus_has_loan_header lhh
LEFT JOIN
    loan_management_app.mst_customer cum
ON
    (
        lhh.mst_customer_id = cum.id)
UNION 
SELECT
    cum.id,
    lhh.mst_customer_id,
    cum.first_name,
    cum.middle_name,
    cum.last_name,
    cum.name_ins,
    lhh.loan_amount,
    lhh.date_granted,
    lhh.loan_duration,
    lhh.status
FROM
    loan_management_app.trans_cus_has_loan_header lhh
RIGHT JOIN
    loan_management_app.mst_customer cum
ON
    (
        lhh.mst_customer_id = cum.id)
INNER JOIN 
        loan_management_app.mst_loan lon
ON
    (
        lhh.mst_loan_id= lon.id)
INNER JOIN 
        loan_management_app.trans_loan_has_interest lhi
ON
        (lhi.mst_loan_id=lon.id)   
INNER JOIN loan_management_app.mst_interest mi
ON 
        (mi.id=lhi.mst_interest_id) ;
```

But it still returns only the people with loans.Any help regarding this would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a LEFT JOIN with mst_customer ... so you're getting all loan_management even if don't have customer.

```
LEFT JOIN
    loan_management_app.mst_customer cum
```

Try to use RIGHT JOIN maybe:

```
RIGHT JOIN
    loan_management_app.mst_customer cum
```

Also, you can use that query, going from 'mst_customer' with all lefts joins. Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM mst_customer mc 
LEFT JOIN trans_cus_has_loan_header tchl ON mc.id = tchl.mst_customer_id
LEFT JOIN mst_loan ml ON ml.id = tchl.mst_loan_id
LEFT JOIN trans_loan_has_interest tlhi ON tlhi.mst_loan_id = ml.id
LEFT JOIN mst_interest mi ON mi.id = tlhi.mst_interest_id
```

I hope this last one will work for you :-)

Comment: You don't need UNION for that case. If you had had another customers table with more rows (and the same columns), you should had to do UNION ALL with customers_2 to get all rows of those 2 tables. Regards.